# Display Primefaces's OverlayPanel when the page loads

Tags: jsf, primefaces

The page shows a Primefaces's `overlayPanel` when the target component (a `commandButton`) is clicked on:

```html
<p:commandButton id="inputBtn" value="Choose a data source" type="button" action="#{dataImportBean.oAuth}"/>
 
<p:overlayPanel
 id="overlaypanel1"
 for="inputBtn"
 dynamic="false"
 widgetVar="inputChooser"
 >
// contents of the overlay panel
</p:overlayPanel>
```

I would need the `overlayPanel` to be displayed when the page loads, without the need to click on the target `commandButton`.

*The use case is: the user had the `overlayPanel` opened but an oAuth flow made the user navigate away from the page. When the oAuth is completed the user is redirected to the page. However the overlayPanel is closed when the page loads, whereas I need the user to be brought back directly to the overlayPanel, for consistency.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the client side API on your widget var. You can use `show()` to show the panel, so in your case: `PF('inputChooser').show()`.

To do this on page load, you could place this after the `p:overlayPanel`:

```html
<c:if test="#{yourCondition}">
<script>$(function() { PF('inputChooser').show() })</script>
</c:if>
```

See also:

- https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/10_0_0/#/components/overlaypanel?id=client-side-api